# Is there such a thing as kosher perry?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, liquor-beer

This might be too obscure for most people, but I want to put it out there anyway. Perry is fermented pears (sort of a pear cider, if you will - from what I read in Wikipedia, perry produced outside the UK is, in fact, called pear cider). While I cannot see any halachic problems with this (it's not made from grapes, and would not be processed in the same place as wine is), and in theory should also be kosher for passover, I have yet to find any indication that there is a kosher certification for perry. If anyone can shed any light on this (and if there is a kosher perry available, let me know!), I would appreciate it.

Comment: Barry, I can honestly say that I've never heard of the product, Kosher or not. Are you sure it is widely available outside the UK generally?

Comment: @SethJ, No, I can't say that it is widely available outside the UK; I recognize that this is a fairly unique drink, but I saw it featured on a show once and was intrigued. Besides, I live in Holland, so in theory I should be able to get access to Perry a bit easier - if it doesn't come all the way from Australia, that is!

Comment: It does sound intriguing, that's for sure.

Comment: @SethJ, it's good stuff.  I made my own once, back when I was set up for home brewing.

Comment: re: halachic problems, the cheapest way to clarify apple juices and ciders (and I assume pear as well) is fining through gelatin.  Kosher companies probably set up a different process.

Comment: the clarification process for beer and cider sometimes uses isinglass not gelatin. the nodeh ben yehuda addresses why this does not render your drink to be unkosher. the reasons being 1)no impact on flavor and 2)it is removed before bottling. Generally alcohol which has fruit in it requires stricter supervision as many companies get their fruit taste from various flavorings. For example one way of making raspberry flavor is from a certain gland on a beaver. The best solution is to learn to make it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

By [Googling for *pear cider kosher*](https://www.google.com/search?q=pear%20cider%20kosher), I found a that the [Kashrut Authority](http://www.ka.org.au/index.php/component/option,com_kosherdb/Itemid,60/catid,109/subcatid,243/) of Australia lists a few such products. (I'm not familiar with that agency, but it's [endorsed](http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php) by the Chicago Rabbinical Council, for what it's worth.)

Lechaim!

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a bit more to work with; I tried looking up Kosher Perry and Kosher Pear cider, but didn't get the same hits you did (the main ones were for a comedian Rick Perry). Still, there has to be something with a London Kashrut!

Comment: You could try calling the London Kashrut agencies.